# c++ function call in a class does not match definition

Tags: c++, class

I'm reading the C++ code below:

```
// Take a whole packet from somewhere.
EthernetII packet = ...;
// Find the IP layer
const IP* ip = packet.find_pdu<IP>();
if(ip) {
    // If the pointer is not null, then it will point to the IP layer
}
// Find the TCP layer. This will throw a pdu_not_found exception
// if there is no TCP layer in this packet.
const TCP& tcp = packet.rfind_pdu<TCP>();
```

The definition of `PDU::rfind_pdu()` is below. My question is, should an argument not be passed to `rfind_pdu()`? And what is the syntax that allows `<IP>` to appended to the function call?

> `template<typename T> const T& Tins::PDU::rfind_pdu(PDUType type = T::pdu_flag) const inline`
>
> Finds and returns the first PDU that
>   matches the given flag.
>
> Parameters `flag` The flag which being searched.

Comment: Looks like you want to read a bit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/3484570) until you have a good understanding of templates and default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

An argument need not *necessarily* passed, since it's *defaulted* to `T::pdu_flag`.

The `<TCP>` notation at the calling site *disambiguates* the template (that's required since the appropriate template instantiation cannot be gleaned from any function parameters since there aren't any). The default argument value will be `TCP::pdu_flag`, whatever that is.